# Creating COM object from C++?

Tags: c#, c++, com, dllexport

I want to create a dll from a C++ code and the use it in C#. Is there a solution of creating COM object from C++ ?
I don't want to use `System.Runtime.InteropServices`.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

Of course that you can write COM+ objects with C++. [Here's a tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/complus/general/article.php/c16639/How-to-Write-a-COM-Component.htm).

Answer (score 4):

You can write COM directly (see @Darin Dimitrov's answer), but you can also use [ATL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Template_Library). My favorite solution to expose C++ code to C# (without COM though) is to use [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI).

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to go about it.

1) Use PInvoke from C# to call into native methods.

2) Use C++-CLI to create a layer that exposes native functionality to C#. This is my recommended approach performance wise.

3) Write the C++ dll as a COM object and access from C#. Requires COM knowledge and hence developement cost.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ATL , it too easy and you just have to register the dll . after that you can use it in all c# programms